# Validação "in" Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Boa tarde, eu preciso validar um DropDown para que se nele existir o valores 1, 2, 3 o usuário não consiga inserir outros valores a não ser os que estão contidos nele.

Eu consegui fazer em **AlunoUpdateRequest** o seguinte:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'classe_id' => 'required|in:' . $this->aluno->classe_id,
```

No meu **AlunoController.php** está dessa maneira:

```
public function update(AlunoUpdateRequest $request, Aluno $aluno)
{
    $aluno->update($request->all());
    Session::flash('notice', 'Atualizado Com Sucesso !');
    return Redirect::to('/aluno');
}
```

O único problema é que não estou conseguindo usar a mesma forma na criação do registro em **AlunoCreateRequest**:

```
public function rules()
{
  return [
    'classe_id' => 'required|in:' . $this->aluno->classe_id,
```

O código é o mesmo. Como resolver ?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Galera, consegui resolver usando a função "exists":
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-exists

Comment: Você poderia colocar mais informações, geralmente a criação de um validator Request é suficiente!

Comment: Esses valores veêm de uma tabela? O que são? tem de dar mais informação para conseguirmos ajudar

Comment: Eles vêm de uma tabela do banco de dados. @Miguel

Comment: @João, o validador Request já foi criado.

Comment: Exato, já foi criado. Você pode: `classe_id  => 'required|exists:classes,id'` ... Verifica a existência do item na tabela classes, coluna id, neste caso. Acho que é qualquer como isso que quer

Comment: Então Miguel, a função que o próprio Laravel dispõe é a "in"; o que você falou é válido, mas eu creio que tem que existir alguma forma de fazer isso em Request sem a necessidade de criar uma função sacou ? @Miguel

Comment: Não dá. O mais proximo que consegue é fazer essa verificação no middleware. Não dá para fazer no request

Comment: Acabei de conseguir. Usei a validação "exists" do Laravel